# How to build flutter APKs on cloud and get downloadable link?

Tags: flutter

I was building flutter apps on my laptop but it takes a lot of time to build these APKs. Is there any way that I can build the APK on some cloud service or say on Travis and get the downloadable link of APK so that I can develop the application faster?

Answer (score 0):

You should purchase your own, VPS, and guide to achieve it, is in official docs: 
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/fastlane-cd#cloud-build-and-deploy-setup

Comment: Isn't there any other way?